# Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add or remove a row into DB, using a button click that redirects back to the same page,, here are my files

**views.py**

```
def favorite_item (request, pk):
    favitem = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    userfav = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    for items in userfav:
        if items.item == favitem:
            items.delete()
        else:
            items = Favorite(item=favitem, user=request.user)
            items .save()

    return redirect('')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<int:pk>/favorite_item/', views.favorite_item, name='favorite_item'),
```

**html**

```
              <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/gold_star.png' %}"></a>
```

but whenever I click it I get the error :

**error**

```
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**Entire Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/3/favorite_item/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django_filters',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'fostania_web_app.apps.FostaniaWebAppConfig']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "F:\django\fostania\fostania_web_app\views.py" in favorite_item
  278.     return redirect('')

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in redirect
  58.     return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in resolve_url
  149.         return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  88.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  632.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /3/favorite_item/
Exception Value: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: mind sharing the entire traceback? Id like to see a little more of the call stack.

Comment: Done, Edited the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for adding the traceback. Its the redirect call. So when you use the redirect shortcut method the string you give it needs to match the name variable in at least one of your configured paths. So when I tried to redirect to nothing in my project with:

```
return redirect("")
```

I get the exact same error because I have no paths configured for that:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:key>/authors/', views.get_authors, name='authors'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home')
]
```

But when i changed my path for home to use the name ="":

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:key>/authors/', views.get_authors, name='authors'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='')
]
```

viola, redirects to home.