# I get the error. NoReverseMatch at /delete_mat/11/ in one of the apps in Django

Tags: django, view, django-urls

> Hail Devs. I created a second app in an existing Django project. The urls.py routes in the app work fine, but the views edit_mat, update_mat and delete_mat, which access the database despite performing the action do not reload the index page. The views that I don't access the database work perfectly.
> No idea what else to do. Can you help?

erro:

```
NoReverseMatch at /delete_mat/11/
Reverse for 'material' not found. 'material' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_mat/11/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'material' not found. 'material' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\webcq\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\webcq\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\webcq',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\webcq\\venv',
 'C:\\webcq\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 17 May 2021 21:27:15 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\webcq\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\webcq\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\webcq\materiais\views.py, line 49, in delete_mat
    return redirect('material') …
▶ Local vars
```

> view.py app

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from materiais.models import EspecComponentes, Componente, Codigo, EspecMaterial
from materiais.forms import EspecComponentesForm



# Create your views here.

...

def create_mat(request):
    form_mat = EspecComponentesForm(request.POST or None)
    if form_mat.is_valid():
        form_mat.save()
        return redirect('material')

def view_mat(request, pk):
    data = {}
    data['db'] = EspecComponentes.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'materiais/view.html', data)

def edit_mat(request, pk):
    data = {}
    data['db'] = EspecComponentes.objects.get(pk=pk)
    data['form_mat'] = EspecComponentesForm(instance=data['db'])
    return render(request, 'materiais/form.html', data)

def update_mat(request, pk):
    data = {}
    data['db'] = EspecComponentes.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form_mat = EspecComponentesForm(request.POST or None, instance=data['db'])
    if form_mat.is_valid():
        form_mat.save()
        return redirect('material')

def delete_mat(request, pk):
    db = EspecComponentes.objects.get(pk=pk)
    db.delete()
    return redirect('material')
```

> urls.py app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'materiais'

urlpatterns = [

  #ok  path('material/', views.material, name='material'),
  #ok path('form_mat/', views.form_mat, name='form_mat'), 
    path('create_mat/', views.create_mat, name='create_mat'),
    path('view_mat/<int:pk>/', views.view_mat, name='view_mat'),
    path('edit_mat/<int:pk>/', views.edit_mat, name='edit_mat'),
    path('update_mat/<int:pk>/', views.update_mat, name='update_mat'),
    path('delete_mat/<int:pk>/', views.delete_mat, name='delete_mat'),

]
```

> The views work, but do not redirect to the view name and return the error:
> NoReverseMatch at /edit_mat/11/
> NoReverseMatch at /update_mat/11/
> NoReverseMatch at /delete_mat/11/

urls.py project

```
from django.urls import include, path
from imagem.views import home, form, create, view, projeto, edit, update, delete
from materiais.views import material, form_mat, create_mat, view_mat, edit_mat, update_mat, delete_mat


urlpatterns = [

 ... urls project... ok
    

    #App Materiais

    path('', include('materiais.urls', namespace='material')),
    path('form_mat/', include('materiais.urls', namespace='form_mat')),
    path('create_mat/', include('materiais.urls', namespace='create_mat')),
    path('view_mat/<int:pk>/', include('materiais.urls', namespace='view_mat')),
    path('edit_mat/<int:pk>/', include('materiais.urls', namespace='edit_mat')),
    path('update_mat/<int:pk>/', include('materiais.urls', namespace='update_mat')),
    path('delete_mat/<int:pk>/', include('materiais.urls', namespace='delete_mat')),

]
```

> form.html

```
          <tbody>

          {% for dbs in db %}

            <td>
               <th>{{dbs.id}}</th>
                <td>{{dbs.espec_name}}</td>
                <td>{{dbs.codigo}}</td>
                <td>{{dbs.espec_material}}</td>
                <td>{{dbs.diametro1}}</td>
                <td>{{dbs.diametro2}}</td>
                <td>{{dbs.peso}}</td>
                <td>
                      <a href="/view_mat/{{dbs.id}}/" class="btn btn-dark">Visualizar</a>
                      <a href="/edit_mat/{{dbs.id}}/" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                      <a href="/delete_mat/{{dbs.id}}/" class="btn btn-danger btnDel">Deletar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

          </tbody>
```

Comment: I belive [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779426/reverse-for-not-found-is-not-a-valid-view-function-or-pattern-name/50779575) will help you. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, it worked. The object was wrongly declared. Thank you. Sure thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `redirect('material:material')` in your views. Which is `<app name>:<url namespace>`

Comment: Yes, it worked. The object was wrongly declared. Thank you. Sure thing!